# When a Pseudo-Cauchy sequence converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta, cauchy-sequences

A Pseudo-Cauchy sequence is: A sequence $(a_n)$ if $\forall$ $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \ N \in \mathbb N$ such that   $|a_{n+1} - a_n| \leq \epsilon\;\; \forall n \ge N$.

I know Pseudo-Cauchy sequence does not always converge. My question is what are the conditions for a Pseudo-Cauchy sequence to converge? For example, let a(n)=F(n+1)/F(n) where Fn is nth fibonacci number. In this example, a(n) is both a Cauchy sequence and pseudo-Cauchy sequence.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1535348, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1237655

Comment: @311411 I checked those pages before but neither of them answers my question. I am asking for conditions that satisfies pseudo-cauchy is cauchy.

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: In the spirit of your question here is another that can offer you some insight into yours:  *Suppose that $E\subset \mathbb R$ is a bounded set.  Find necessary and sufficient conditions on $E$ so that all pseudo-Cauchy sequences of points in $E$ are convergent.*